# java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set with no empty row

Tags: java, mysql

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Connection connection;
    PreparedStatement ps;
   
    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/testdb", "root", "pokemon12");
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserName = ? AND Password = ?");
        ps.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
        ps.setString(2, String.valueOf(jPasswordField1.getPassword()));
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        
        if(rs.next()){
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
            setVisible(false);
            NewApplication1 mf = new NewApplication1(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2));
            mf.setVisible(true);
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Username Or Password Are Invalid");
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

i dont know why i keep getting java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set even tho my sql table isnt empty and the row im trying to get also isnt empty, it happens when i try to select the last and second to last row in the table, excuse my lack of knowledge im very new to sql.

Comment: The question marks are only placeholders. Java does nothing to format the input. This means since there are no quotes, it's trying to treat your username and password as column names. Try putting both the question marks in single quotes (`'?'`)

Comment: That looks like Plain Text Passwords being used here!!! **V.v.bad**

Comment: @Jesse i tried putting the ? between single quotes and i got the following error java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: Oh right I think it's the other way around. My mistake. Taking a second look at the error, it seems to me that it might be caused by the fact that you're trying to get results from the result set in your `else` statement. Considering the only condition in the `if` statement is `rs.next()`, `rs` won't have any results if the else block is executing and therefore can't get the strings you're asking for.